# How to create a list of all words in a text file except for words with duplicate letters

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to iterate through a list, and append all the words to a new list, excluding words that have duplicate letters.

Example:

```
words = ['cat', 'car', 'weevil', 'lizard', 'mammoth', 'cabbage', 'aardvaark']
newlist = []

for word in words:
    for letter in word
        if word.count(letter) > 1:
            pass
        else:
            newlist.append(word)

print(newlist)
# Result
['cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'weevil', 'weevil', 'weevil', 'weevil', 'lizard', 'lizard', 'lizard', 'lizard', 'lizard', 'lizard', 'mammoth', 'mammoth', 'mammoth', 'mammoth', 'cabbage', 'cabbage', 'cabbage', 'aardvaark', 'aardvaark', 'aardvaark']
```

The code doesn't actually work because a word like weevil for example will satisfy the word.count(letter) condition for the letter 'w', pass twice for the two 'e's and then satisfy three more times after the two 'e's which is why it's appearing in the list four times.

Perhaps I'm approaching this from the wrong angle, but I'm really stumped at how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC your question, you could use

```
>>> [w for w in words if len(set(w)) == len(w)]
['cat', 'car', 'lizard']
```

If a word has no duplicate letters, then its length will be the length of the set of its letters. The rest is just putting this into [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: Awesome! This worked, and was 10 lines of code more efficient than the answer I got from my lecturer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `filter` functionality provided by the standard library

```
words = ['cat', 'car', 'weevil', 'lizard', 'mammoth', 'cabbage', 'aardvaark']
newlist = list( filter(lambda x: unduplicate_letter(x), words) )

def unduplicate_letters(w):
    for letter in w:
       if w.count(letter) > 1:
           return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because it is appending the word everytime it checks for a letter. You should check for all letters before appending the word, so you can add a check variable to see if all letters pass then append the word. for example:

```
    words = ['cat', 'car', 'weevil', 'lizard', 'mammoth', 'cabbage', 'aardvaark']
    newlist = []

    for word in words:
        check = 0
        for letter in word:
            if word.count(letter) > 1:
                check = 1

        if (check == 0):
            newlist.append(word)


    print(newlist)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['cat', 'car', 'lizard']
```

Answer (score 0):

> In [1]: def duplicate(word):
>      ...:     for i in word:
>      ...:         if word.count(i) > 1: return True
>      ...:     return False
>
> In [4]: new = [word for word in words if not duplicate(word)]
>   In [5]: new
>   Out[5]: ['cat', 'car', 'lizard']

Answer (score 0):

We can use Python `set()` to help with a more simple solution:

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.py
from __future__ import print_function

words = ['cat', 'car', 'weevil', 'lizard', 'mammoth', 'cabbage', 'aardvaark']

newlist = list()

for word in words:
    # if word inlude multiple occurances of same character, set()
    # will keep only one occurance.
    if len(set(word)) == len(word):
            newlist.append(word)

print(newlist)

$ python /tmp/tmp.py
['cat', 'car', 'lizard']
```